# Getting kinect 3D position value

Tags: kinect, data-conversion

I'm working with a Kinect 1414 with the library kinect4WinSDK (processing). 
First, I have my depth value as a raw value between 6400 and 30 000. I convert it with this:

```
if (raw==0x0000) z=0.0;
else if (p.raw>=0x8000) p.z=4.0;
else p.z=0.8+(float(p.raw-6576)*0.00012115165336374002280501710376283);
```

However, my x and y value are in a range [0,1] for x and [-1,1] for y. I wanted these value in meter. Can you help me?
Thanks,

Yoann

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to get the corresponding real world 1 meter in computer space(Kinect space). The kinect itself is not measuring respect to any standard unit. So you need to map a real world 1 meter to Kinect distance. For this get a 4 meter distance and mark it with kinect skeleton hand for both ends and  get the distance in the computer space and let's say it is x. Now if you get a d distance in real world then the corresponding Kinect space distance is (x/4c)*d. C can be calculated.